# "All My Files" option in Open/Save dialog get 100% CPU on Mountain Lion for a couple of minutes?

Tags: macos, finder

"All My Files" option in Open/Save dialog get 100% CPU on Mountain Lion for a couple of minutes?

How to solve this?

Mainly this happens twice: once before drawing anything on screen and once again after displaying the files.

After about two minutes you can use the dialog, but the problem reapers every time you click on All My Files.

I do have a SSD+HDD setup on my machine. Console does not say anything interesting.

Comment: Do you know what process is taking up 100% CPU? Also, do you have any idea how many files?

Comment: Same here - mainly when opening that dialog from within Safari/WebKit.

Comment: It's not a problem related to the number of files and the CPU is got by the app doing the file opening, whichever it is.

Comment: The same thing happens to me in every application on Mountain Lion.

Comment: Do you have _a lot_ of version control repositories? Excessive git/hg metadata can bloat Spotlight. Possible information in [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62855/is-all-my-files-slow-because-of-my-git-and-svn-repos)

Comment: I do have .hg/.git repositories, even quite big ones but I removed them from Sportlight search but without noticing a huge performance gain.

Comment: Do you have many video files on your drive? Particularly .avis? I sometimes find that QTKitServer (which I believe does icon previews for videos) gets hung up, or just takes a long time if there are lots of videos to process. Check Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by the general [slow spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/65486/21703) problems with OS 10.7.5 and 10.8.2.  What version of Mountain Lion are you running?  How long has this been a problem?  If you're running 10.8.2 you might try [this workaround](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/66062/21703).