# Spotlight re-index every time I restart/boot iMac

Tags: macos, imac, spotlight, indexing

I have an iMac Late 2006 with Lion installed. I don't know since when, but since 3-4 weeks ago I am having this problem.

The point is, every time I restart my iMac or boot it, Spotlight starts to reindex again.

I already test to disable Spotlight, remove /.Spotlight-V100 and enable Spotlight again but it didn't solve it. I don't know how to debug/detect the problem but it is so bad, because it impacts on iMac performance...

I don't know if it is important, but I also have installed Windows 7 on Bootcamp. However it is marked as non-indexing volume on Spotlight's Preferences. I also tried to repair permissions, but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure it's doing full index? My computer reindexes on startup, but it's not a full index.

Comment: I can't be sure, but yesterday it says "22 hours remaining" and the progress bar was 1/3 filled. Today, 7 days remaining and just a bit of progress bar filled http://drop.difun.de/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202012-09-29%20a%20la%28s%29%2019.32.57.png

Comment: Ooh. You may want to just let it finish. If after it has finished it starts reindexing *again*, then I'd be a bit concerned.

Comment: But it will never ends because it starts every time I need to reboot. Lion was installed more than 1 year ago and Spotlight index was fine, the issues is around 3-4 weeks ago

Comment: Okay then. That is odd. You may want to consider a manual reindex. It may be that your index has been corrupted and is causing it to reindix. Run `sudo mdutil -E /` in Terminal. You'll be prompted for your password and then it'll start the indexing process. Note that this could take awhile, depending on the amount of data you have.

Comment: I think that i tried that already. Anyway I am going to try it again :)

Comment: Do let me know how that works.

Comment: If it started after upgrading to 10.7.5, it could be the same issue as in [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/65486).

Comment: Yes. That's exactly the problem. The point now is to find a solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" it forcing a new indexation but excluding the User directory. What happens? It is too slow, but has an end. Not is eternal. When it finish, you can add again your User directory and, after it finish, you can reboot safely without scare :)